What makes this a group of three pointers?
While reading "Reversing - Secrets of reverse engineering" I came across this piece of code:
UnknownStruct->Member1 = 0;
UnknownStruct->Member3 = &UnknownStruct->Member2;
UnknownStruct->Member2 = &UnknownStruct->Member2;
UnknownStruct->Member4 = &UnknownStruct->Member2;

which comes from the following asm lines:
7C921A3E MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
7C921A41 XOR EDX,EDX
7C921A43 LEA ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]

7C921A46 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX],EDX
7C921A48 MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+4],ECX
7C921A4B MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ECX],ECX
7C921A4D MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+C],ECX

The author states:

The [...] three members are initialized in a somewhat unusual fashion: They are all being initialized to point to the address of the second member. What could that possibly mean? Essentially it tells you that each of these members is a pointer to a group of three pointers (because that’s what pointed to by UnknownStruct->Member2—a group of three pointers).

I am confused as to how UnknownStruct->Member2 is a group of three pointers - how should this snippet be looked at to deduce that or is this a mistake?
With each of the members pointing to &UnknownStruct->Member2, which is a single address, how does it suddenly turn into a 3-pointer group?

Is it really assigning the member's own address back to that member?

I'm guessing that the original Member2 points to an array of 3 pointers, and he's using "group" to mean "array".

He could also be depending on the fact that consecutive struct members are stored sequentially, as in arrays. So a pointer to Member2 is effectively a pointer to the beginning of an array that contains Member2, Member3, and Member4. This isn't portable, but reverse-engineering can take implementation details into account.

And if the code being reverse-engineered is assembly, not C, portable C is irrelevant.

It would probably have been better if he'd declared a single member containing an array, then used array indexes.

Perhaps the author knows what it is? It reminds me of a node in a tree structure, as a struct with pointers parent, left, and right, plus a value. Pointing back to itself is not unheard of for a tree root.

An array would be initialized by a loop or a call to memset.  The fact that it is initialized by 3 statements suggests that it is a group of 3.

It is not an array, as they are not contiguous (there's a 4 byte gap between Member3 and Member4).  The fact that they're being initialized together (and to the same value, and via the same base pointer in ECX) indicates that they are related somehow, thus calling them a "group" seems reasonable.

@ChrisDodd There is no gab between member3 and member4. But calling it a group is still reasonable, because there's no evidence (so far) that the members are forming an array. And, in the end, it couldn't even be possible to know if they are an array of just three consecutive members since the compiled code could be the same.

A group, an array, a set, a bunch. It doesn't matter. It's the same concept. When you RE back into C or a pseudo-language, some ambiguities will necessarily arise because different C structs and statements will translate to the same machine code. So you cannot describe everything in terms of C syntax at first. You are focusing too much on the wording and to few on the code. Read the code, not the words.

@MargaretBloom member3 is 4 bytes at ECX+4.  member4 is 4 bytes at ECX+12.  There's a 4 byte gap between them

There is nothing of substance here. This is just the author’s own language, as there is nothing technical in C or assembly language that is a “group,” nor is it a word commonly used in computer science or software engineering that would have any particular relevance here.
Reverse engineering commonly involves attempting to divine the intention of the author of code. To this end, somebody engaging in reverse engineering may form hypotheses about the code author’s intentions and construct narratives that help them understand those intentions. The textbook author’s use of the word “group” may be part of this.
If there is any meaning to be found in why the author used the word “group,” it is in the surrounding or prerequisite text of the book.

Not knowing the definition of UnknownStruct I think it's just a reference that
Member2, Member3 and Member4 (three consecutive pointers) all point to the address of Member2 which is a single (32-bit) pointer.
Or (jokingly) maybe its a Secret of reverse engineering ?
